# Can WPF handle Guids from LINQ to SQL?

Tags: c#, wpf, linq-to-sql

I stumbled on a strange problem. In my WPF (.NET 4) window I have a simple combobox (DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="Id"). When I load the window I set the combobox's ItemSource property to context.Currencies.ToList() using LINQ to SQL. The Currency table in SQL is simply *[Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, [Name] char NOT NULL*. In .NET this translates to *Id = System.Guid, Name = System.String*.

The problem I'm having is that the call to combobox.ItemsSource = context.Currencies.ToList(); throws a FormatException (Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx)).

**What I can't understand is why is this error thrown?**

If I leave LINQ to SQL out of the picture, define a "test" class - public class Test { public Guid Id; public string Name; }, set the comobox.ItemsSource to a `List<Test>` which contains some entries, then everything works.

If I do this:

```
combobox.ItemsSource = context.Currencies.Select(c => new { c.Id.ToString(), c.Name }).ToList()
```

then everything works.

I tried setting the current thread's Culture and UICulture to "en-US" beforehand as well (just in case it's a culture problem, my default culture is "et-EE"), but that didn't help either.

I looked at the generated LINQ to SQL classes from the designer, but couldn't find any properties to alter which might have helped with this error.

**Am I missing something here or is this really a bug in the .NET framework?**´

PS! The Currency table contains valid entries (valid Guids).

Comment: What happens when you don't assign the list to the combobox but just call `context.Currencies.ToList();`?

Comment: Then everything is fine. I can easily use the list for whatever purpose, for example I can assign it to datagrid.ItemsSource no problem... But the combobox doesn't like it for whatever reason.

Comment: Do you have a binding on `SelectedValue` ?

Comment: Thomas - thank you! I did have a binding and I found the cause of my error as well. I had a FallbackValue = 1 defined for the binding, after removing it everything works. The property was scrolled out of view, so yes - something I missed. Write an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Thomas pointed out, I had a binding on SelectedValue and it turns out the binding also contained a FallbackValue = 1. After removing the fallback property everything works. The property was scrolled out of view, so indeed it was something I missed.